# linux using vim editor questions using /etc/passwd file unmodified

Tags: linux, vim

I was having trouble figuring out how to find out how to find answer to these 2 problems. I know I'm on the right track but could figure out how. I had been experimenting with the `rm` and `-d` commands in vim but couldn't get the right result. Some help would be very appreciated. Thanks

1. Using the vim editor with the `/etc/passwd` file, write a vim command to
   delete all lines where field 1 (the userid field) does NOT contain any digits
2. Using the vim editor with the `/etc/passwd` file, write a vim command to
   append the userid field (field 1) to the end of field 8. When finished,
   the first and last fields of each line should be the same.

Comment: My apologies. I have rephrased my question, sorry for that.

Comment: Don't use `vi /etc/passwd`. Instead, use `vipw`

Comment: If you're having a hard time finding documentation for vi, you might try looking at how you'd do it with `sed`.  The `sed` way and the `vi` way are often quite similar.

Comment: used :%v/^[^0-9:]*/d but it is highliting all feilds, even those with 0-9 in them up to the :

Answer (score 0):

Since this seems to be some homework assignment, I'll just give you some help but wount provide an answer.
For 1) your looking for an command applied to the range of all lines. There is a character used to address all lines. Thereafter you define a precondition with a regex, which will match all 1st fields without digits. Keep in mind that the first field starts at the beginning of the line and ends with the `:` as a field separator, whereby the field should not contain digits and doesn't contain `:`. Finally you add the command to delete the line.

For 2) you need backreferences. Also, usually the passwd file only has seven fields. To append to field 8, you'll have to create that field.

Enjoy your assignment. ;-)

Comment: Not a homework assignment, but thanks for the feedback!